# How to add some pixels on the texture in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm making an Android application to add a line like a header which is like this for example:

[image: Header]

(it's a line of some colored pixels, it was kinda zoomed in)

on top left of this:

[image: Main texture]

I don't know if it's possible to add some pixels on top of a texture with OpenGL or not. Or we must put it in an Bitmap, load it to texture and then combine it with the main texture.

Comment: Are you trying to modify the texture with these pixels? Or just draw them over the texture after you rendered the texture? For the first case, `glTexSubImage2D()` should do the trick. Otherwise, you can define a new texture with the extra pixels.

Comment: @RetoKoradi please post your full answer in the first case with a trivial sample code, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a row of pixels, the best way is to create a texture from them, and then draw them just like any other texture. Depending on your exact use case, there are at least two approaches:

1. If you always want to render that row of pixels over the existing texture, and in the same place relative to the original texture content, you can modify that texture with `glTexSubImage2D()`. Say you have an array of bytes `rowBytes`, that contains the RGB values for the row of `nPixels` pixels you want to add. Bind the existing texture, and then call:

   ```
   GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, nPixels, 1,
                          GLES20.G_RBB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                          ByteBuffer.wrap(rowBytes));
   ```
2. Create a new texture for the row, using the standard calls you use for any other texture (`glGenTextures`, `glBindTexture`, `glTexImage2D`). For just a single row of pixels, specify the height as 1. Then render the texture the same way you already render your existing textures, which is typically by rendering a textured quad for the area you want covered.